# How to check if an object key is in another object of objects

Tags: javascript

I have the following objects:

```
const allMembers = {
    "-Lz8YxHiwp8QZW3TqAFn": {
        "first": "foo",
        "last": "bar",
        "uid": "-Lz8YxHiwp8QZW3TqAFn"
    },
    "-Lz8YxHqQXWoaGOFRLrO": {
        "first": "foo",
        "last": "bar",
        "uid": "-Lz8YxHqQXWoaGOFRLrO"
    },
    "-Lz8YxHsMItaaTVNyQRE": {
        "first": "foo",
        "last": "bar",
        "uid": "-Lz8YxHsMItaaTVNyQRE"
    },
    "-Lz8YxHwuVBMWl0Go6C5": {
        "first": "foo",
        "last": "bar",
        "uid": "-Lz8YxHwuVBMWl0Go6C5"
    },
    "-Lz8YxHy0S-QkDaE1PkX": {
        "first": "foo",
        "last": "bar",
        "uid": "-Lz8YxHy0S-QkDaE1PkX"
    },
}

const attendanceData = {
    "-Lz8YxHiwp8QZW3TqAFn": true,
    "-Lz8YxHqQXWoaGOFRLrO": true,
    "-Lz8YxHsMItaaTVNyQRE": true,
    "-Lz8YxHwuVBMWl0Go6C5": false,
    "-Lz8YxHy0S-QkDaE1PkX": true,
    "-Lz8YxIFA1XGVmaNfNr3": false,
    "-Lz8YxIJVZnIIj7RgEzg": false,
}
```

I need to clean up the allMembers to only return if it's found as true in attendanceData.
Here is my attempt but it's obviously not working.  Also the way I'm doing it has to loop the first one over the other times.

```
const membersHere = Object.keys(allMembers).filter(memEl => Object.keys(attendanceData).find(attendEl => memEl == attendEl));
```

Comment: What result do you actually want? If it's just the list of IDs then: `Object.keys(allMembers).filter(m => attendanceData[m])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Convert the `allMembers` object into an array of key value pairs using [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries).
- Filter the items that have value `true` using [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
- Transform the array back to an object using [Object.fromEntries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromentries).

```js
const 
  allMembers = {'-Lz8YxHiwp8QZW3TqAFn': {first: 'foo',last: 'bar',uid: '-Lz8YxHiwp8QZW3TqAFn'},'-Lz8YxHqQXWoaGOFRLrO': {first: 'foo',last: 'bar',uid: '-Lz8YxHqQXWoaGOFRLrO'},'-Lz8YxHsMItaaTVNyQRE': {first: 'foo',last: 'bar',uid: '-Lz8YxHsMItaaTVNyQRE'},'-Lz8YxHwuVBMWl0Go6C5': {first: 'foo',last: 'bar',uid: '-Lz8YxHwuVBMWl0Go6C5'},'-Lz8YxHy0S-QkDaE1PkX': {first: 'foo',last: 'bar',uid: '-Lz8YxHy0S-QkDaE1PkX'}},
  attendanceData = {'-Lz8YxHiwp8QZW3TqAFn': true,'-Lz8YxHqQXWoaGOFRLrO': true,'-Lz8YxHsMItaaTVNyQRE': true,'-Lz8YxHwuVBMWl0Go6C5': false,'-Lz8YxHy0S-QkDaE1PkX': true,'-Lz8YxIFA1XGVmaNfNr3': false,'-Lz8YxIJVZnIIj7RgEzg': false},
  filteredMembers = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(allMembers).filter(([k]) => attendanceData[k])
  );

console.log(filteredMembers);
```

You can also do it using [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
const 
  allMembers = {'-Lz8YxHiwp8QZW3TqAFn': {first: 'foo',last: 'bar',uid: '-Lz8YxHiwp8QZW3TqAFn'},'-Lz8YxHqQXWoaGOFRLrO': {first: 'foo',last: 'bar',uid: '-Lz8YxHqQXWoaGOFRLrO'},'-Lz8YxHsMItaaTVNyQRE': {first: 'foo',last: 'bar',uid: '-Lz8YxHsMItaaTVNyQRE'},'-Lz8YxHwuVBMWl0Go6C5': {first: 'foo',last: 'bar',uid: '-Lz8YxHwuVBMWl0Go6C5'},'-Lz8YxHy0S-QkDaE1PkX': {first: 'foo',last: 'bar',uid: '-Lz8YxHy0S-QkDaE1PkX'}},
  attendanceData = {'-Lz8YxHiwp8QZW3TqAFn': true,'-Lz8YxHqQXWoaGOFRLrO': true,'-Lz8YxHsMItaaTVNyQRE': true,'-Lz8YxHwuVBMWl0Go6C5': false,'-Lz8YxHy0S-QkDaE1PkX': true,'-Lz8YxIFA1XGVmaNfNr3': false,'-Lz8YxIJVZnIIj7RgEzg': false},
  filteredMembers = Object.entries(allMembers).reduce(
    (r, [k, v]) => (attendanceData[k] && (r[k] = v), r),
    {}
  );

console.log(filteredMembers);
```

**Other relevant documentations:**

- [Comma operator (,)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)

Comment: You seem to have mixed up `Object.fromEntries` and `Object.entries` in your explanation.

Comment: @Unmitigated Nice catch, updated!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `reduce` method:

```js
const allMembers = {
    "-Lz8YxHiwp8QZW3TqAFn": {
        "first": "foo",
        "last": "bar",
        "uid": "-Lz8YxHiwp8QZW3TqAFn"
    },
    "-Lz8YxHqQXWoaGOFRLrO": {
        "first": "foo",
        "last": "bar",
        "uid": "-Lz8YxHqQXWoaGOFRLrO"
    },
    "-Lz8YxHsMItaaTVNyQRE": {
        "first": "foo",
        "last": "bar",
        "uid": "-Lz8YxHsMItaaTVNyQRE"
    },
    "-Lz8YxHwuVBMWl0Go6C5": {
        "first": "foo",
        "last": "bar",
        "uid": "-Lz8YxHwuVBMWl0Go6C5"
    },
    "-Lz8YxHy0S-QkDaE1PkX": {
        "first": "foo",
        "last": "bar",
        "uid": "-Lz8YxHy0S-QkDaE1PkX"
    },
}

const attendanceData = {
    "-Lz8YxHiwp8QZW3TqAFn": true,
    "-Lz8YxHqQXWoaGOFRLrO": true,
    "-Lz8YxHsMItaaTVNyQRE": true,
    "-Lz8YxHwuVBMWl0Go6C5": false,
    "-Lz8YxHy0S-QkDaE1PkX": true,
    "-Lz8YxIFA1XGVmaNfNr3": false,
    "-Lz8YxIJVZnIIj7RgEzg": false,
}

const reduced = Object.entries(allMembers).reduce((data, [key, value]) => {
  if (attendanceData[key] ?? false)
    data[key] = value;
  return data;  
}, {});

console.log(reduced);
```

Comment: `?? false` is redundant here.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Code:

```js
const allMembers = {'-Lz8YxHiwp8QZW3TqAFn': {first: 'foo',last: 'bar',uid: '-Lz8YxHiwp8QZW3TqAFn',},'-Lz8YxHqQXWoaGOFRLrO': {first: 'foo',last: 'bar',uid: '-Lz8YxHqQXWoaGOFRLrO',},'-Lz8YxHsMItaaTVNyQRE': {first: 'foo',last: 'bar',uid: '-Lz8YxHsMItaaTVNyQRE',},'-Lz8YxHwuVBMWl0Go6C5': {first: 'foo',last: 'bar',uid: '-Lz8YxHwuVBMWl0Go6C5',},'-Lz8YxHy0S-QkDaE1PkX': {first: 'foo',last: 'bar',uid: '-Lz8YxHy0S-QkDaE1PkX',},}

const attendanceData = {'-Lz8YxHiwp8QZW3TqAFn': true,'-Lz8YxHqQXWoaGOFRLrO': true,'-Lz8YxHsMItaaTVNyQRE': true,'-Lz8YxHwuVBMWl0Go6C5': false,'-Lz8YxHy0S-QkDaE1PkX': true,'-Lz8YxIFA1XGVmaNfNr3': false,'-Lz8YxIJVZnIIj7RgEzg': false,}
  
const result = Object
  .keys(allMembers)
  .filter((k) => attendanceData[k])
  .reduce((a, k) => (a[k] = allMembers[k], a), {})

console.log(result)
```